# Copy data from one sheet to another sheet without deleting previous copied rows

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub CopyRows4()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim cl As Range
    Dim str As String
    Dim RowEmpCrnt As Long
    Dim RowUpdCrnt As Long
    Dim WshtEmp As Worksheet

    Set WshtEmp = Sheets("Employee Data")
    Set rng = WshtEmp.UsedRange 'the range to search ie the used range
    str1 = "Executive" 'string to look for
    str2 = "Working"

    Sheets("Executive").UsedRange.Value = ""

    RowUpdCrnt = 3

    For Each cl In rng.Columns("E").Rows
        If cl.Text = str1 Then
          RowEmpCrnt = cl.Row
          If WshtEmp.Cells(RowEmpCrnt, "X").Value = str2 Then
            ' If both column "A" and column "E" contain the correct value
            ' copy it to next empty row on sheet 2
            cl.Range("a3:z3").Copy Sheets("executive").Cells(RowUpdCrnt, 1)

            RowUpdCrnt = RowUpdCrnt + 1
          End If
        End If
    Next cl
End Sub
```

Here I want to copy data from `Sheets(Employee Data)` starting from column A3 for only those column/rows that satisfy the conditions.

Comment: What does the data in `Employee Data` look like?

Answer (score 0):

First some issues with your code.

**Issue 1**

I have never seen a worksheet cleared in this way: `Sheets("updated").UsedRange.Value = ""`

The most obvious problem is that it does not clear any formatting.  I also imagine that with a large worksheet it is slow.  I suggest:

```
With Sheets("updated")
  .Cells.EntireRow.Delete
End With
```

or

```
Sheets("updated").Cells.EntireRow.Delete
```

The use of a `With` statement does not make a big difference in this case but it can make code much clearer.  I suggest you look up `With statement` within the VBA Editor's Help

**Issue 2**

`For Each cl In rng` looks at every cell in `rng`:  `A1`, `B1`, `C1`, ..., `A2`, `B2`, `C2`, ..., , `A3`, `B3`, `C3`, ..., etc. If `rng` is `A1:Z500` then all 1300 cells will be checked.

If the cells with a value of "Yes" are scattered then this will be what you intended.  However, I assume that all the cells with a value of "Yes" are in a single column.  I have used column "E" in my test data; you will have to replace E" with the correct column identifier for your data.

`For Each cl In rng.Columns("E")` says I am only interested in column "E".  This gives `E1:E500` which is not what I want.

`For Each cl In rng.Columns("E").Rows` says I am interested in the rows within column "E".  This gives: `E1`, `E2`, `E3`, ...

**Issue 3**

`If cl.Text = str Then`

This will give you the effect you require in this case but you need to understand what this means because it will not give the effect you require in all situations.

`cl.Value` gives the Excel value for the cell.  `cl.Text`, with some exceptions, gives you the display value for the cell.  The exceptions are all associated with some of the more obscure horizontal alignments so I will ignore them.

For a string, the Excel value and the display value will be the same.  For a formatted numeric value they may not be the same.  So if Excel value 123 is formatted with two decimal digits the display value will be 123.00.

**Issue 4**

`Sheets("updated").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)`

This is very clever but:

- it may not do quite what you expect in every situation,
- may be the cause for some rows being overwritten
- it unnecessarily complicated.

I do not like "complicated".  You may be able to look at this string and quickly interpret what is does but your less able peers may not.

To be honest I am not happy with my `rng.Columns("E").Rows` which is also, in my view, "complicated".  It requires a solid understanding of the Excel Object Model to know what it does.  I have only used it because I wanted to change as little of your code as possible.  If this were my code I would have avoided the need for this construct.

`End(xlUp)`, `End(xlDown)`, `End(xlToLeft)` and `End(xlToRight)` are the VBA equivalents of keyboard <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Up Arrow</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Down Arrow</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Left Arrow</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Right Arrow</kbd> controls.

Assuming the cell at the bottom of column A is empty, `Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)` notionally moves the cursor up to top of the column or the first cell with a value.  `Offset(1, 0)` then moves down one row.

When you first use this command, you have just cleared the worksheet so this command goes to the top of the column then down one so the first output row is 2.  Perhaps this is what you want but you are getting it by accident not design.

More importantly, if any of the rows you copy from worksheet "Employee Data" has no value in column A, it will be overwritten.  This may be the cause of the problem you report.

I have removed this command.  Instead I have a new variable RowUpdCrnt.  (Sorry, in the first version of this answer, I had RowEmpCrnt.)  I initialise RowUpdCrnt to 1.  Change this to 2 if you want a blank line at the top.  I then add 1 to RowUpdCrnt every time I copy a row across.

**Summary**

I hope the above all makes sense to you.  Ask if anything is unclear.

**My suggested code**

```
Sub CopyRows3()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim cl As Range
    Dim str As String
    Dim RowUpdCrnt As Long

    Set rng = Sheets("Employee Data").UsedRange 'the range to search ie the used range
    str = "Yes" 'string to look for

    Sheets("updated").UsedRange.Value = ""

    RowUpdCrnt = 1

    ' In my test data, the "Yes"s are in column E.  This For-Each only selects column E.
    ' I assume all your "Yes"s are in a single column.  Replace "E" by the appropriate
    ' column letter for your data.
    For Each cl In rng.Columns("E").Rows
        If cl.Text = str Then
             'if the ell contains the correct value copy it to next empty row on sheet 2 &  delete the row
            cl.EntireRow.Copy Sheets("updated").Cells(RowUpdCrnt, 1)
            RowUpdCrnt = RowUpdCrnt + 1
        End If
    Next cl
End Sub
```

**New section in response to comment that "Yes" in both columns A and X are required before a row should be moved**

I think this code meets the additional requirement:

```
Sub CopyRows4()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim cl As Range
    Dim str As String
    Dim RowEmpCrnt As Long
    Dim RowUpdCrnt As Long
    Dim WshtEmp As Worksheet

    Set WshtEmp = Sheets("Employee Data")
    Set rng = WshtEmp.UsedRange 'the range to search ie the used range
    str = "Yes" 'string to look for

    Sheets("updated").UsedRange.Value = ""

    RowUpdCrnt = 1

    For Each cl In rng.Columns("A").Rows
        If cl.Text = str Then
          RowEmpCrnt = cl.Row
          If WshtEmp.Cells(RowEmpCrnt, "X").Value = str Then
            ' If both column "A" and column "E" contain the correct value
            ' copy it to next empty row on sheet 2
            cl.EntireRow.Copy Sheets("updated").Cells(RowUpdCrnt, 1)
            RowUpdCrnt = RowUpdCrnt + 1
          End If
        End If
    Next cl
End Sub
```

Comment: For string "Yes" i want to test it for two different columns say A and X. If the conditions for both the columns get satisfy then only the data should be copied to another sheet.

Comment: @user3217660 I have added a new section in response to your new requirement.

Comment: Thnx for ur prompt response. I want the copied data to paste in different range with different selection(e.g. copy range (B3:Z3) and paste range ( D3:AC3).

Comment: It sounds as if this is a separate requirement.  I can give you some examples but the command you want is `SourceRange.Copy Destination := DestinationTopLeftCell`.  The `Destination :=` is optional.  There is an example in my new code: `cl.EntireRow.Copy Sheets("updated").Cells(RowUpdCrnt, 1)`.  Here the source range is `cl.EntireRow` and the top left cell of the destination range is `Sheets("updated").Cells(RowUpdCrnt, 1)`.  Does that help?

Comment: sheets("Employee Data")Range("B3:Z3").Copy Sheets("updated").Range("B3:Z3")  i used this one but is not working (error 9)

Comment: The destination should be the top left cell of the destination range.  Try replacing `Sheets("updated").Range("B3:Z3")` with `Sheets("updated").Range("B3")`

Comment: this is copying only one row but i need all the rows to be copied which meet if condition

Comment: What only copies one row?  With my test data `CopyRows4` copies all rows with "Yes" in both column "A" and column "X".

Comment: the code sheets("Employee Data").range("B3:Z3").Copy Sheets("updated").Range("B3").Cells(RowUpdCrnt, 1) is copying only first row and creating its multiple duplicates down the rows

Comment: `sheets("Employee Data").range("B3:Z3")` is the source range for this `Copy` statement.  It refers to row 3 so if you have this `Copy` statement in a loop, it will always copy the same row.  I do not understand why `Sheets("updated").Range("B3").Cells(RowUpdCrnt, 1)` is not invalid VBA.  It returns the very strange address of Range("B" & 3+RowUpdCrnt-1).  I suspect you want `Sheets("updated").Cells(RowUpdCrnt, 1)`.

Comment: in the test data copy rows 4 i want that if both the conditions got satisfied the data from "sheet1" should be copied from cl a3 for that row and similarly pasted in cl a3 of sheet2

Comment: You are not using the code I posted.  I cannot diagnose problems in code I have not seen.